# How do I import data from a ColdFusion LDAP query .cfm file into an SQL table?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, ldap

I have made connection to the LDAP server and can export my data into an excel spreadsheet.  However, I need it inserted into an SQL table for future use.  I cannot figure out how to link my query to the LDAP server to the SQL database.  Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming your `cfldap` command returns a query object, loop through those results and insert your data one row at a time.

Comment: So I could do a <cfquery name="getldapinfo" datasource="LDAP">
select my data
from ldap_server
</cfquery>
<cfloop>
<cfquery name="insertldapdata" datasource="SQLtable">

This is where I get lost.  I have tried an INSERT INTO, but it doesn't work.

Comment: btw - I am using a template to call my LDAP connection information.  <cfinclude template="template.cfm>

Comment: Your first comment describes the correct general idea.  However, the term, doesn't work, is vague.  Please edit your question and add the code for the loop along with some details of what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry.. Learning how to properly explain my issue along with learning how to work with this code.  When I write the INSERT INTO part of the code, it will not insert the data into my SQL table.  I also have it set to export to an excel document.  The exporting will work, but the inserting into the SQL table does not.  If I do INSERT INTO mysqltable, then select the top 100 of that table, it doesn't have any data.  I might be over thinking this though.  I'm going to start over and try it again.. Maybe I missed a tag someplace...

Comment: <cfquery name="getldapinfo" datasource="ldapserver">
SELECT login, firstname, lastname, email
FROM   ldapserver
</cfquery>
<cfloop>
<cfquery name="insertLDAPData" datasource="sqldb">
INSERT INTO sql_table
select login, firstname, lastname, email
FROM
The FROM is where I am getting held up on when I try to write this code.  I need to insert the LDAP information into sql_table, but when I do the INSERT INTO, I still have to do a select/from.  Where is the FROM supposed to be from?  The table that I am inserting this into?

Comment: I just figured it out!  I am not doing a select/from.  I am doing an INSERT and VALUES!  Finally was able to get it to insert data into my SQL table, however, now its timing out before all of the data can be inserted.. Need to narrow down my SELECT statement on my ldap query!  Thank you for all your help!  You helped me think about it and figure it out @DanBracuk!!!